# Installing a specific kernel version on debian linux

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel

I want to install kernel 4.5 on a Debian Jessie machine (I want to be as close as possible to a specific machine I have in production).

Currently the version on the backports repo is 4.7, and I can't find a way to obtain 4.5

How do I look for versions that are not the latest? Any repository I can add that holds an archive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until false;' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/archive
echo 'deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20160529T223338Z/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-snapshot.list
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-4.5.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
```

But you don't need this, because 4.7 is fully compatible with 4.5 and there are no significant performance issues at all. I do not recommend to use kernel 4.5, but if you want...

Comment: It's for investigation purposes, not really usage in production. checking for specific vulnerabilities

Comment: Also, how did you know to look for that specific snapshot. They seem to be organized by date, not by version. Is there a way to look for a version in them?

Comment: @TomKlino: Yes. From http://snapshot.debian.org/ you can navigate to http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/?cat=l and choose what version do you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GUI [Ukuu Kernel Upgrade Utility](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html) for debian too, although it installs the Ubuntu-Kernels then on your Debian-System, which could lead to problems (I am not sure)

Just download the .deb package and install with

```
dpkg -i ukuu-latest-amd64.deb
```

(at the moment the debian download seems offline, I hope they [fix that](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu/issues/60))